# Prove every subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

This isn't a homework problem.  I've seen a proof of the following statement online, and I think the proof is suspect, or at least incomplete.

> **Theorem**.  Every subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable.
>
> *Proof*.  Let $A \subseteq N$.  Suppose without loss of generality $A$ is not finite.  Since $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered, $A$ has a least element $a_{1}$.  Since $A$ is infinite, $A - \{a_{1}\} \neq \emptyset$, and again by the well-ordering of $\Bbb N$, there is a least element $a_{2} \in A - \{a_{1} \}$.
>
> Proceeding inductively, for each $k \in \Bbb N$, we can find $a_{k} \in A - \{a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{k - 1} \}$ with $a_{1} < a_{2} < \dots < a_{k}$.
>
> Then $A = \{a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots \}$, and so $A$ is countable, as desired.

I don't think this proof is complete.  It should be shown that $A \subseteq \{a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots \}$, right?  I don't think this is obvious because pretend we have a different ordering on $\Bbb N$, i.e., the following ordering:

$$1 < 3 <5 < \dots < 2 < 4 < 6 < \dots$$

Then if $A = \{1, 2, 3, \dots \}$, using the above procedure, we would only get the odd numbers, so we wouldn't be able to say $A \subseteq \{1, 3, 5, \dots \}$.  Does my objection to the proof of the theorem make sense?  How do you complete the proof (i.e., how do you show the containment I want to show)?

Comment: $1 < 3 <5 < \dots < 2 < 4 < 6 < \dots$ seems like an unusual (read: suspicious) order to me. Shouldn't $2$ have a predecessor, or is that not important?

Comment: @pjs36 I'm not sure what you mean (or whether it is important or not).  I think with the ordering specified, the set $\{1, 3, 5, \dots, 2, 4, 6 \dots \}$ is still a well-ordered set.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I didn't like the constant stream of comments. You should perhaps behave less frantically when someone is posting an answer to your question.

Comment: @user46944 You're probably right. It just caught me off guard that your order didn't "feel" like the usual order on $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Nice! Actually, I deleted the constant stream about 3 minutes ago, so I'm not sure why you decided to comment about it and delete now.  Also, I was originally planning to accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in A$

By induction, $a_k \geq k$ for all $k$. Therefore, $a_x \geq x$. Hence, $x$ was achieved at some point.

Comment: His argument is that we will never achieve $a_x$ even, since there is always a next odd number.

Comment: You misunderstood his question, I think. He is not asking about the order he mentions, nor about the sequence he mentions as a set. I think he simply doesn't think the fact is trivial as implicitly stated.

Comment: Well, this answer is correct if we assume the usual ordering of $1 < 2 < 3 < \dots $.  This was my original question -- how do you show this rigorously.  According to @AsafKaragila (who deleted his answer because I commented too much on it -- huh? I know...) it doesn't matter which order you take on $\Bbb N$ -- we can still prove any subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Nice argument.  :)

Comment: I didn't read Asaf's answer, but I think he meant that the concept of enumerability doesn't depend on the ordering. The proof of this theorem uses the well-ordering of the natural numbers as a tool, but that doesn't mean that the concept of enumerability depends on an order. You can consider a different order, all right, but why would that be useful? (at least, for the purposes of the theorem).

Comment: Well, it might be interesting to prove that $\Bbb N$ under the ordering $1 < 3 < 5 < \dots < 2 < 4 < 6 < \dots$ satisfies that every subset is countable.  So an alternate argument would be needed in that case.  I didn't specifically ask for it, but I guess it makes sense that it exists because countability doesn't depend on ordering, as you said, even though the original proof did.

Comment: Would this be an acceptable argument for the different ordering case?  Let $\Bbb N$ have any ordering (and suppose we know $\Bbb N$ with the usual ordering satisfies that every subset is countable).  Then every subset of $\Bbb N$ with this new ordering is in bijection with a subset (the same subset) of $\Bbb N$ under the usual ordering (via the identity map), and this is countable, so the original subset is countable.  Is that argument correct?  If so, it doesn't seem so mysterious or difficult.

Comment: Yes, your argument is right, just because why would an alternate argument be needed? Consider your statement:

"Prove that $\mathbb{N}$ under the ordering $1<3<5<⋯<2<4<6<…$ satisfies that every subset is countable." 

The "under the ordering $1<3<5<⋯<2<4<6<…$ " does not say anything. We are talking about a set and infinite subsets of it, and we want to make bijections from it to $\mathbb{N}$. It is like saying:

- I just proved that plants are not animals, but I'm unsure on how to prove that plants which have green leaves are not animals.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I totally understand what you are saying, but the original proof was dependent on the ordering of $\Bbb N$.  That was one of the main points of me asking this question: the original proof depended on the ordering, and switching the ordering made that proof false.

Comment: The original proof "depended" on the ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ as an argument, not as an hypothesis.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I'm not so sure.  The fact that the argument depends the ordering means the ordering of $\Bbb N$ is an assumption we are making at the beginning (even if we don't explicitly state it).  But I completely agree with you that once we prove it for the usual ordering, it holds for any other ordering trivially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this argument:

Let $S_1 = \lbrace 1, 3, 5, ...\rbrace$ and $S_2 = \lbrace 2, 4, 6, ...\rbrace$ all with the order $1 < 3 < 5 < ... < 2 < 4 < ...$. By that process, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are countable. That implies that $S_1 \cup S_2$ is countable.

Comment: Well, assuming we know that a finite union of countable sets is countable, this would be OK in showing that $\Bbb N$ with the specified order is countable.  But I needed to show that *every subset* of $\Bbb N$ is countable, so this argument would be incomplete in that regard.

Comment: @user46944 if you want any subset of $\Bbb N$, just split any subset into the subsets of $S_1$ and $S_2$ and then take the union to show countability.

Comment: @user46944 I think this would be a more elementary rigorous explanation, because I thought of the OP's explanation before, but it didn't seem "right" enough because of your objections.

Comment: But you would need to know the finite union of countable sets is countable, and I think the proof of that requires that you know any subset of $\Bbb N$ is countable.  So the argument becomes recursive.

Comment: Consider $X \subset S_1$ It's countable. Consider $V \subset S_2$ also countable. Now $X \cup V$ is also countable.

Comment: @user46944 I.E, any subset of $\Bbb N$ can be expressed as a union of subsets of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Comment: How do you know $X \subset S_{1}$ is countable?  Isn't that what we wanted to show in this problem?

Comment: @user46944 You got me :).

Comment: Hahaha, trust me I go around in these circles all of the time.

Comment: @user46944 Actually, hold on. I think that it's obvious that the usual ordering holds for those sets, so we can assume they are countable.

Comment: @user46944 Cause we aren't playing around with infinites and orders, we can use the fact that the number of elements missing from the subset is finite

Comment: @user46944 which means that it's also countable.

Comment: My brain hurts.  I'm having trouble following anything anymore lol